# How do I download songs in a playlist in Music?

Tags: itunes, music, bug, itunes-match

I used to be able to download all of the songs in a playlist from iCloud at once in Music, but the download button is no longer showing in the playlist title area it used to. It does show next to individual songs that haven't been downloaded, however selecting all and right-clicking now longer shows a download button in the context menu either. The only way I have found to download more than one is to go to the album, and the download button shows in the album title area.

Any ideas on how to re-enable the download button? Is this a bug?

Note: it does not seem to make a difference if the playlist only contains content I have purchased, uploaded with iTunes Match, or added to my library from Apple Music.

Album view with download button visible:

[image: Album with download button visible]

Playlist view missing the download button: [image: Playlist with no download button visible]

Download button missing from menu: [image: Download button missing from menu]

Comment: The only work-around I have found is to select all songs in the "Songs" playlist that Music creates, selecting them all, then clicking download in the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

In playlists you can click on the three dots at top right and select "Download" from there.

Comment: There is only "remove download" in that menu. I have updated the post to indicate this.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII If there is only a "Remove" entry, the playlist is already downloaded.

Comment: but the songs in the playlist aren't - otherwise they wouldn't have the cloud download button on those that have not been downloaded to the system

Comment: the option is "remove from playlist" not remove downloaded file. The files doesn't have to be downloaded for you to edit iCloud playlists

Comment: and, another good indicator that a song file has not downloaded is that it does not show the "reveal in finder" context item for that song, and I am unable to drag it to another application. The "remove download" button in the playlist context menu will remove only the files for the songs that have already been downloaded - but not all of them have been.

Comment: I have now solved the problem by going to the "Songs" Library playlist and selecting all songs - then downloading them via the context menu. This option didn't show in any other playlist view when I selected multiple songs that hadn't been downloaded.